# Get int value of UITextField

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get the int value of a UITextField. 
I have set the keyboard type to:

```
textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

And I try to get the int value like this:

```
NSLog:([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [textfield.text intValue]]);
```

Even though I enter integers it always returns 0. Whats wrong?

Comment: try with `NSLog:([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [textfield.text intValue]]);`

Comment: nope, still doesn't work

Comment: @Ayush: `%d` and `%i` are equivalent.

Comment: Is the outlet set correctly? Ie I guess the textfield is nil. Usually an outlet is a property and you would access it with `self.textfield.text`

Comment: @JoshCaswell I know, but still I thought lets give a try with `%d`, Since I had used many times.

Comment: Can you include some examples of strings that cause this? Also, why are you converting from string to int and back to string? Just use the string. Also also, `NSLog()` requires a _literal_ string for its first argument, so you should be doing `NSLog(@"%i", [textfield.text intValue]);`, or (nonsensically) `NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [textfield.text intValue]]);`

Comment: As @JoshCaswell said can you please include a log of you textfield i.e `NSLog(@"%@",textfield.text)`

Comment: I don't turn it back to a string, I compare the int with another number in my app. What do you mean with the examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is, textfield is nil. Is the outlet set correctly? Usually an outlet is a property and you would access it with `self.textfield.text`.

You could log the textfield and see if its nil.

Comment: no its not a property, I declear it as an instance and initialize it in the viewdid load

Comment: And you checked that it is NOT nil at the time you want to log?

Comment: There are several ways. Most sensible is to use debugger. But I don't want to explain that now, so just do `NSLog("%@", textfield);` where you want to log the int value. You will see a memory address in console or something like `0x00000 <nil>` or just `(null)`if its nil (you can paste the output here if you're unsure).

Comment: I cant use that line, it says "Incompatible pointer types passing char[3] to parameter of type nsstring"

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Show how you declared textfield and how you did the nslog I suggested above!

Comment: I added a @ before the " so I got this: `<UITextField: 0x7537cb0; frame = (680 300; 200 30); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x755e1e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7547690>>``

Comment: Right, my fault with the missing @. So the text field exists. Now do `NSLog(@"%@", textfield.text);` and `NSLog(@"%d", [textfield.text intValue];` and post both outputs

Comment: I solved it, in the same method I removed the enterd text, or set it to 0. So that was the problem. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You say it "always returns 0," but as your example is written, `NSLog` yields nothing in the log because of the stray colon.

Removing the colon, your line performs fine, albeit with a compiler warning. To fix that, you'd want to change it to:

```
NSLog (@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [textfield.text intValue]]);
```

Of course, 'fine' in my case may not be the same for you; as others have pointed out, is the value of `textField.text` an instance of NSString containing a textual representation of a number?

Comment: i'm not quite sure what you mean, but the entered number is stored in an int variable which I later just use to compare with another number

Comment: So you're saying that `textField.text` is a number? Not trying to be flippant, but that's not what you're illustrating in your example.

Comment: textField.text is a number since the keyboard type is number pad, so it should be a number